# Custom lookup is not being registered in Django

Tags: python, django

I've created a custom lookup. I'm using it for a query, however, when I do so, the error `Related Field got invalid lookup: lcb` is thrown.

I'm assuming that this is because this custom lookup isn't being registered properly. As you'll see below, I've tried several things and I'm lost as to what the issue is.

Here's my code:

**tenants/views.py**

```
from main.lookups import *

def find_tenants(request, house_id):
    house = HouseListing.objects.get(pk=house_id)
    applications = HousingApplication.objects.filter(date_from__gte=house.available_from)
    applications = applications.filter(pets__lcb=house.allowed_pets.values_list('id', flat=True))

    context = {'house': house, 'applications': applications}
    return render(request, 'landlords/find-tenants.html', context)
```

**main/lookups.py**

```
from django.db.models import Lookup, ManyToManyField


# Custom lookups

@ManyToManyField.register_lookup
class ListContainedBy(Lookup):
    lookup_name = 'lcb'

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        lhs, lhs_params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection)
        rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
        params = lhs_params + rhs_params
        return '%s <@ %s' % (lhs, rhs), params
```

I find this very strange, as [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-lookups/) suggest registering the lookup in the `AppConfig`, or in `models.py`. I've tried both of these things and neither worked.

**Traceback**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/landlords/find-tenants/5/

Django Version: 1.10.2
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:
['main.apps.MainConfig',
 'tenants.apps.TenantsConfig',
 'landlords.apps.LandlordsConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'django.contrib.postgres',
 'imagekit']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Users/mightyspaj/Development/Projects/housingfinder/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Users/mightyspaj/Development/Projects/housingfinder/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/Users/mightyspaj/Development/Projects/housingfinder/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/mightyspaj/Development/Projects/housingfinder/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/mightyspaj/Development/Projects/housingfinder/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/mightyspaj/Development/Projects/housingfinder/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  23.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/mightyspaj/Development/Projects/housingfinder/housingfinder/landlords/views.py" in find_tenants
  132.     applications = applications.filter(pets__lcb=house.allowed_pets.values_list('id', flat=True))

File "/Users/mightyspaj/Development/Projects/housingfinder/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in filter
  796.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "/Users/mightyspaj/Development/Projects/housingfinder/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  814.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "/Users/mightyspaj/Development/Projects/housingfinder/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in add_q
  1227.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "/Users/mightyspaj/Development/Projects/housingfinder/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in _add_q
  1253.                     allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,

File "/Users/mightyspaj/Development/Projects/housingfinder/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py" in build_filter
  1178.             lookup_class = field.get_lookup(lookups[0])

File "/Users/mightyspaj/Development/Projects/housingfinder/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py" in get_lookup
  694.             raise TypeError('Related Field got invalid lookup: %s' % lookup_name)

Exception Type: TypeError at /landlords/find-tenants/5/
Exception Value: Related Field got invalid lookup: lcb
```

**All the things I've tried so far**

1. Registering the lookup in the `MainConfig.ready()` function
2. Registering the lookup in the `find_tenants()` view
3. Registering the lookup in `main/models.py`
4. Registering the lookup as a `Field` instead of a `ManyToManyField`
5. Registering the lookup using `ManyToManyField.register_lookup()` instead of a decorator
6. Changing `%s <@ %s` to `%s = %s`. I thought the issue might be that it thinks my SQL is invalid

Answer (score 2):

#### Edit 2

It looks like some of this confusion might be sorted out in later versions of django... Edit 1 below is for 1.10, but the code is different in tip so perhaps this has now been fixed. You could try upgrading to 1.11 and see if that fixes it. But the options I listed below are still worth a try if that doesn't work.

#### Edit 1

I realized that I misread the exception in my initial answer. Actually, the exception being hit is the one in `django.db.models.fields.related.ForeignObject.get_lookup`, and the code there is much clearer that django does not support custom lookups on Relational fields:

```
class ForeignObject(RelatedField):

    ...

    def get_lookup(self, lookup_name):
        if lookup_name == 'in':
            return RelatedIn
        elif lookup_name == 'exact':
            return RelatedExact
        elif lookup_name == 'gt':
            return RelatedGreaterThan
        elif lookup_name == 'gte':
            return RelatedGreaterThanOrEqual
        elif lookup_name == 'lt':
            return RelatedLessThan
        elif lookup_name == 'lte':
            return RelatedLessThanOrEqual
        elif lookup_name == 'isnull':
            return RelatedIsNull
        else:
            raise TypeError('Related Field got invalid lookup: %s' % lookup_name)

    ...
```

There <del>are a couple of things</del> is one thing you could try to get it to work though:

1. Implement a custom lookup on one of the fields through the many to many relationship, so you'd have a query like

   ```
   applications = applications.filter(
       pets__id__lcb=house.allowed_pets.values_list('id', flat=True))
   ```

   I was able to get something along these lines to work using the `IN` operator.
2. <del>Alternatively, you may be able to subclass the `ForeignObject` you are using and override `get_lookup` so that it doesn't throw an exception for your new operator... no doubt there would be a bit of a fiddle you'd have to do to get that to work though.</del> **Edit:** I tried this, and it didn't work because it's more complicated than that, and for a join operation it's the implicit field from the right-hand table that is the `Field` used, so subclassing the `Field` for the left hand table was not enough. Option 1 definitely seems the right way to go about it.

#### Original answer

I believe the exception is telling you that django won't attempt to use custom lookups for relational fields. Given that you mention it I'm guessing that `pets` is a `ManyToManyField`, i.e. a relational field, and so I guess that your lookup has been registered, django is just refusing to use it.

The bit of code in django you are hitting (in `django.db.models.sql.query.Query.build_filter()`) is:

```
....
if field.is_relation:
    # No support for transforms for relational fields
    num_lookups = len(lookups)
    if num_lookups > 1:
        raise FieldError('Related Field got invalid lookup: {}'.format(lookups[0]))
....
```

I can't say I fully understand the rationale, but that certainly would explain why whatever mechanism you tried to use to register the lookup you got the same result.

It seems to be a not-very-well documented issue. The only thing online I could find out about it (with 10 minutes searching) was [this](http://osdir.com/ml/django-developers/2016-05/msg00210.html), where someone else came to the same conclusion.

Comment: `applications.filter(pets__id__lcb=house.allowed_pets.values_list('id', flat=True))` throws the error: `TypeError - can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list`

With this I'm using the `%s <@ %s` operator though (which I need)

Comment: The latest Django version is also `1.10.3`, not `1.11`. I was on `1.10.2` and just tried upgrading to this - the problem still exists.

Comment: Hey, you wanted to know why your custom lookup wasn't being used... I think I answered that :-). At what point does it throw `TypeError`? Are you now getting into your `as_sql()` method?

Comment: It throws the `TypeError` when it reaches: `applications = applications.filter(pets__lcb=house.allowed_pets.values_list('id', flat=True))`. And what is your question about the `as_sql()` method?

Comment: I could just subclass the `ForeignKey` object. I'll try that and get back to you

Comment: The question about `as_sql()` was whether now you had put the custom lookup on the base `Field` class so it gets used for `id` (I assume you did that?) the code gets into your `as_sql()` method, which would demonstrate that the lookup was now at least registered. If that's working, then you've got past the first hurdle and now just need to debug exactly what you should put in there.

Comment: As listed in the things I've already tried, I've already tried registering it as a `Field` instead of a `ManyToManyField`. It still produces the same error

Comment: For Edit 1 option 2, can you please provide an example? If it works using that method I'd be happy to award you the bounty :)

Comment: I'll see if I can, but can I check: did you try registering the lookup on `Field` *and then* doing the lookup through id, i.e. `pets__id__lcb=house.allowed_pets_values_list('id', flat=True)`? I think that's the best way to go about this, and I think you should be able to get it to work because I was able to reproduce your problem (using the `IN` operator at least, I don't know what the `<@` operator does and can't find any information on it) and then fix it by doing this.

Comment: I had a go, but couldn't get it to work, so I've updated my answer. Good luck with it, hope you get it to work, and if you do and find out something different then post an answer!

Comment: Thanks for helping out, I appreciate it. As for what `<@` does, you can read about it [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html). It's different to `IN`

Comment: Ran into this exact issue on a project using Django 2.1.3 but basically the same exact code works, same exact query, perfectly fine using Django 1.8.