# Django custom __in lookup

Tags: django

I get custom lookup for filtering foreign key field from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59544914/5594305).

```
from django.db.models import Lookup

class EfficientInLookup(Lookup):
    lookup_name = "ineff"

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection):
        lhs, lhs_params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection)
        rhs, rhs_params = self.process_rhs(compiler, connection)
        params = lhs_params + list(rhs_params)
        return "%s IN (SELECT unnest(ARRAY(%s)))" % (lhs, rhs), params
```

But I have an error in the string `lhs, lhs_params = self.process_lhs(compiler, connection)` when I am trying use it.

Using:

```
queryset = queryset.filter(child__id__ineff=[1,2,3]
```

Error:

```
int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'list'
```

How can I write a custom lookup for foreign key fields?

Comment: what is `ineff` ?

Comment: @NishantNawarkhede It is the my custom lookup name. see EfficientInLookup class